# I found problem with edit of Test Case in KIWI TCMS

Tags: kiwi-tcms

we have small problem with KIWI TCMS. A some test case editing icon has appeared on the main menu that never disappears and is still there.

When I open a Test Case, the right icon will appear at the far right.

Have any of you encountered a similar problem?

[image: screenshot from KIWI TCMS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reported in GitHub already https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/991